# Filling array in java

Tags: java

So basically I am trying to fill the array[] element with 9 values, however I am not sure how to get the index within this code. I want it to fill the next element in the array each time.

```
public boolean check(int data[][], int x, int y){
int array[] = new int[9];
int xmax = x+3;
int ymax = y+3;

        for(int i = x; i<xmax; i++){
            for(int j = y; j<ymax; j++){
                array[] = data[i][j];//array[what here?]
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: By what pattern do you want array values copied? I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: You are looping 2d array and trying to fill 1d array? any reason?

Comment: the question is not clear, if you want to fill `array[]` it should be on the left side of `=` and for index you can use a simple counter variable

Comment: So I can sort it and check for duplicates. Is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = x; i < xmax; ++i) {
    for (int j = y; j < ymax; ++j) {
        array[3 * (i - x) + (j - y)] = data[i][j];
    }
}
```